# What's the best resource qualifiers should I use in creating a responsive layout?

Tags: android, android-studio, responsiveness, android-resource-qualifiers

I've been trying to make my simple calculator app responsive with different mobile phone screen sizes using **Density** as my resource qualifier, I specifically used the **hdpi, xhdpi, xxhdpi,** and **xxxhdpi** for my layouts.

This is how my file structure looks like for reference:
[File structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4zt0T.png)

I then tested my app on different phones of my friends and my app seemed to have no problem with displaying responsive layout on modern phones regardless of its size, but then the problems started when I tried to run my app on large phones with low-density (around 320ish dpi), like layout designs intended for **hdpi** phones are being displayed on a large phone since the phone itself has a low density.

This is how it looks like for reference:
[Reference_1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0J8ib.png)
[Reference_2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8teMm.png)

Is there any solution to this? Or should I just use different resource qualifiers in creating a responsive layout? And I'm also wondering, is there any more efficient way to create a responsive layout without using constraint layout alone (assuming that an app has a complex design)? Since for example, I have 10 fragments in my app, I don't think creating three or more different XML resource qualifiers per fragment is efficient.

Thank you so much for reading my problem, I hope you can help me with this, thanks!

Comment: There is pretty much never any reason to vary XML by density.  Are you familiar with `dp` vs `px`? Which one are you using?

Comment: Hello @RyanM, thank you for reaching out. So far I'm only using `dp` for my projects, and in regards to my app (the one posted above), I almost haven't really used physical sizes (aside from `padding` on the edges of the app) since most of my layout are dealing with recycler views, horizontal and vertical linear layout which uses layout weights.

Comment: I'm confused why you're needing different layouts for different densities, then.  `dp` should just scale correctly without any need to do anything.  Are you sure you're not looking for something like smallest-width, width, or height as a qualifier?

Comment: @RyanM Yes maybe I don't really need to use a qualifier after all since I just also found a way to scale my text and dimensions without using any resource qualifier using [ssp](https://github.com/intuit/ssp) (scalable sp) and [sdp](https://github.com/intuit/sdp) (scalable dp), so I just need to design my layout using my smallest intended screen size, then it will resize automatically as the screen size increases. It works now btw, thanks for pinpointing a solution.